# is it possible to overload a final method

Tags: java

In java we cannot override a final method but is it possible to overload ?

Comment: When you tried it what happened?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, overloading a final method is perfectly legitimate.

For example:

```
public final void doStuff(int x) { ... }
public final void doStuff(double x) { ... }
```

Comment: Is it legal to drop the final keyword in the overload?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, but be aware that dynamic dispatch might not do what you are expecting! Quick example:

```
class Base {
    public final void doSomething(Object o) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    public void doSomething(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Int");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Base b = new Base();
    Base d = new Derived();
    b.doSomething(new Integer(0));
    d.doSomething(new Integer(0));
}
```

This will print:

```
Object
Object
```

Comment: Yes, because both objects created in the main method are given the highest parent data-type `Base`, they will both print "*Object*". Because the `Derived` instance has an "*is a*" relationship with the class `Base`, this object can be casted to `Derived` to invoke the method that prints "*Int*".

Comment: @IanCampbell Exactly `( (Derived) d ).doSomething( 1 );`

Comment: Dynamic dispatch happens when you override methods, not with overloading.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, very much possible.

A small program to demonstrate it:

```
class A{
    final void foo(){ System.out.println("foo ver 1 from class A"); }
    final void foo(int a){ System.out.println("foo ver 2 from class A"); }
    }


class B extends  A{
    final void foo(long l){ System.out.println("foo ver 3 from class B"); }
    // final void foo(){ System.out.println("foo ver 1 from class A"); } NOT ALLOWED
}

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String [] args){
        B obj = new B();

        obj.foo();
        obj.foo(1);
        obj.foo(1L);
    }   
}
```

Output:

```
foo ver 1 from class A
foo ver 2 from class A
foo ver 3 from class B
```

Answer (score 2):

**YES**,  why not? It is as legal as overloading non-final methods.

> **But you cannot override them** (you already know it).

Eg :

```
public final void func(String x) {/* code */}
public final void func(double x) { /* more code */ }
public final void func(int x) { /* yeah I have still more code */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is possible.

You can examine this kind of things by writing small Java classes.

```
class TestClass{
   final public  void testMethod(){

   }

   final public  void testMethod(int i){

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
class a {
  final void method1(int a,int b) {
    System.out.println("super class");
    int d = a+ b;
    System.out.println(d);
  }
}
class b extends a{
  final void method1(int a) {
    System.out.println("sub class");
    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
public class c {
  public static void main(String ar[]) {
    b m = new b();
    m.method1(10);
  }
}
```

Comment: You should format your code and add something to explain your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can overload but not override.

Answer (score 0):

yes overloading final method is possible in java.As final methods are restricted not to override the methods.

while overloading argument list must be different type of the overloading method.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can overload the final methods