# Overloading final method in derived class with derived argument

Tags: java

I got into a situation perfectly described in this post(one of the answers) in: [is it possible to overload a final method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988077/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-final-method)

My question is if there is a way to execute the Derived class method, or another way... It would help a lot in my project to avoid duplicated code just for casting and doing the same operations inside the methods(which are many).

My concern is just to keep the code in one location for maintenance and debugging, and I cant find a way by myself. 
Thanks in advance.

```
class Base {
  public final doSomething(Object o) {
    System.out.println("Object");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  public doSomething(Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Int");
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Base b = new Base();
  Base d = new Derived();
  b.doSomething(new Integer(0));
  d.doSomething(new Integer(0));
}
```

Comment: Why is your base method `final`? It sounds like you want to be able to override it . . .

Comment: Well, the short answer is that I dont control that part of the code. And the reason is that it have some operations inside that cant be left out if one was to override it.. but it was not my call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to invoke a method overloaded in a child class is to invoke it on a reference of the child class type. You'll need a cast

```
((Derived) d).doSomething(new Integer(0));
```

which might cause a `ClassCastException` or invoke it on a variable of the appropriate type

```
Derived d = new Derived();
d.doSomething(new Integer(0));
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking, well if there is no way, there isn't. thanks for the help anyway.