# Is there a way to "seal" a method in Java? (It may not be overridden)?

Tags: java, android

I have an abstract class, that requires 3 methods to be overridden when inherited. But there is one other method I would really like to seal, so it does not get overridden. It contains important logic for the entire class to work and I want to avoid that the user kills the functionality by doing an override where he/she shouldn't.

Is there a way to achieve this?
Or at least a way to signal the user "don't do that!"?

How would you approach such a requirement?
Any suggestions welcome!
Cheers

/edit it's a difference between overriding and overloading, thanks for the comments!

Comment: make it as a final

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to overload a final method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988077/is-it-possible-to-overload-a-final-method)

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan How is that a duplicate?

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that. Overloading is not overriding.

Comment: it's not a duplicate - it's asked the other way round - your posted question is going for how-to-override and I asked about how-to-avoid-override. they are similar, yes, but not duplicated as a user (like me) who isn't aware that he needs "final" in his search query is unlikely to find the question you posted. so please remove your downvote, thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `final` to make the method non-overridable:

```
public abstract class NewClass implements NewInterface{

    @Override
    public  abstract void show();

    public  abstract NewClass show1();

    // This method cannot be overridden
    public  final void show2(){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you declare your method as `final` (eg. `public final void myMethod()`) then it will not be allowed to be overriden.